# Checkbox is not firing event when onClick or onChange

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I don't know why my checkbox is not firing event on jQuery.
Here is my table structure:

```
div id=example1
--table
  --tr
      --td + icon to check line item
      --td setOff select box
      --td checkbox class="fill"
```

and I'm doing this:

```
jQuery('#example1').on('click','.fill',function(){
    alert($(this).is(":checked"));
   });
```

but it's not working, it doesn't `alert(Hello)` and i also tried onChange but still no alert.

I can print Hello in console but cannot alert

Comment: Make sure you included jquery library or not??

Comment: its there other event working great

Comment: jsfiddle be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery you could use the click function. 
Lets say that this is your table

```
<div id='example1'>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th></th><th>Row Text</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td class='fill'><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the corresponding javascript would be :

```
$('#example1 td').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: i tried that way too but not working i'm trying on() becuse row is being dynamically generated